# how to Generate .war file in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, war

I know how to generate .war file in Eclipse. Now, I switched to Android Studio 1.5, Now, I am trying to generate .war file in Android Studio. I tried to use the same procedure as eclipse: file -->export -->web --> war file. But the options are different in Android Studio. I will use .war file in Apache tomcat user AWS (Amazon web services). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android Studio is for building Android apps. WAR files are for servers. You may wish to consider using an IDE that supports both (e.g., IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: Actually, generating warfiles for i-jetty containers on Android is pretty common. AFAICT, though, you have to write some custom Gradle functions to package the warfile created by the plugin to be i-jetty compatible.

Answer (score 0):

So their is no option to generate .War files in android studio.

Comment: Not true. There is a [warfile plugin for Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html).